# ploting histogram with timedelta series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, timedelta

I have some series of data, which is a timedelta data type. I wanted to plot these timedelta into a bar diagram where the y axis should only be marked in hours instead of some other format. Previously, when I was trying with a line plot in matplotlib, it showed some not understandable numbers. The following is the sample of my timedelta series of pandas:

```
date
2020-04-11   0 days 02:00:00
2020-04-12   0 days 03:00:00
2020-04-13   0 days 02:00:00
2020-04-14   0 days 03:00:00
2020-04-15   0 days 01:00:00
2020-04-16   0 days 03:00:00
Freq: D, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

When I am trying to plot it in matplotlib, it results in a plot with y axis values look weird to me.
[image]

Please help me to work out with the plots, where the y-axis tick labels should be in `01:00`, `02:00` like format.

Eagerly waiting for some of the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way is to convert the deltas in seconds and define a `FuncFormatter`.
This is my test series and my final plot:

```
2020-04-11   02:00:00
2020-04-12   03:00:00
2020-04-13   05:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

```
def delta(x, pos):
    out = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)  )
    return out
            
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
form = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(delta)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(form)
ax.plot(s.index, s/np.timedelta64(1,'s'))
ax.set_yticks(s/np.timedelta64(1,'s'))
ax.set_xticks(s.index)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Luigi, its really a good information. I can see what you did is a great things, but tour data are in pandas dataframe type. However, I have the data as a timedelta series, which doesn't allow me to separate the date index from the timedelta values. So, please provide any solution for series data instead of dataframe.

Comment: @sambehera assuming your series is named `s`, you can replace `df['date']` with `s.index` and replace `df['delta']` with `s`

Comment: thanks @tdy for the correction. I edited the answer with a pd.Series